# Не удаётся открыть источник файл "..." Visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-c++

...-это название файла, так как там 483 ошибки я не стал писать их все.
Ещё при запуске пишет:
Следующий проект устарел:
"Название проекта"
Выполнить его сборку?
На какие кнопки б не нажимал пишет:
Возникли ошибки в сборки. Продолжить запуск последний успешно построенный вариант?

Да нет, серавно ошибка одна: не удалось запустить программу "и путь к проекту"
Не удаётся найти указаный файл.

Никак не могу решить, в интернете нет похожих проблем.

*Пишу на С++
*Написанный код не имеет ошибок

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В таких случаях проще создать новый проэкт, закрыть студию - переписать в новый проэкт чисто соурсы старого, открыть проэкт и обновить дерево проэкта новыми соурсами, чем копать что там в студии случилось.